# C# WPF Change Frame Source

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, frame, uicontrol

I have the following folder structure in my project:

[image]

In the UserControls folder are "L_Menu.xaml" and "LS_Account.xaml". These are both simple user controls.
On the “L_Menu” user control there is a frame control which is empty for now, so the property “Source” is still `null`.

Now I want to set the source property of the frame to the uri of the “LS_Account” user control by a click event.
I use the following uri: `"pack://application:,,,/src/Content/UserControls/LS_Account.xaml"`.

```
myFrame.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/src/Content/UserControls/LS_Account.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

When executing the code I get the following error message:

"The resource "src/content/usercontrols/src/content/usercontrols/ls_accout.xaml" cannot be found."

Why is the “new” source attached to the source of the “L_Menu” user control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know how.

Just use this.

```
yourFrame.Navigate(yourUri);
```